# Default access modifier for a Java constructor

Tags: java, constructor, access-modifiers

Can anybody explain what the default access modifier is for an **explicit no-arg constructor** (and other constructors)?

Comment: See also, for the implicit/default constructor: [What's the access modifier of the default constructor in java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22007143/whats-the-access-modifier-of-the-default-constructor-in-java)

Answer (score 61, accepted):

Constructors are the same as methods in this respect - if you don't give an explicit public, private or protected then the constructor gets the default "package private" visibility. It can be called from within the same class or from any other class in the same package, but not from subclasses in a different package (so if a class has only package-visible constructors then any subclasses must be in the same package).

A private constructor prevents any *other* class from instantiating this one, but you can have a public static factory method within the class that calls its own private constructor. This is a common pattern for things like singletons.

Answer (score 41):

**JLS 8.8.9 Default Constructor**

> If a class contains no constructor declarations, then a default constructor that takes no parameters is automatically provided:
>
> if the class is declared public, then the default constructor is implicitly given the access modifier public;
>       if the class is declared protected, then the default constructor is implicitly given the access modifier protected;
>       if the class is declared private, then the default constructor is implicitly given the access modifier private; otherwise,
>       the default constructor has the default access implied by no access modifier.

Comment: The OP specifically asked about "an explicit no-arg constructor", not the default constructor.

Comment: @Raedwald: works when we add no-arg constructor in addition to the parameterized-constructor.

Answer (score 6):

**-** A `constructor` will have a **access-control** of type `default` when **no** access-modifier is defined **explicitly**. So this constructor will have a **Package Level Access**. Classes which are defined within that package as that of the class with this default constructor will be able to access it and also the classes that extend this class containing the default constructor will be able to access it via inheritance.

**-** If the **constructor** is made `private`, then only the **code within that class** can access this.

**Singleton example**

```
public class Test {

  private static Test uniqueInstance = new Test();

  private Test(){}

  public static Test getInstance(){

    return uniqueInstance;

 }


}
```

**-** Even **non-static** `inner classes` with in the class has **access to its Private memebers and vice-versa.**

**Eg:**

```
public class T {


    private T(){

        System.out.println("Hello");
    }

    class TT{

        public TT(){

            new T();
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args){

        T t = new T();
        T.TT i = t.new TT();

    }

}
```

Answer (score 3):

It differs depending on whether you're writing a constructor for a regular class or an enum:

- For classes, the answer is given by [JLS §6.6.1](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.6.1):

  > A class member or constructor declared without an access modifier implicitly has **package** access.
- For enums, the answer is given by [JLS §8.9.2](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.9.2):

  > In an enum declaration, a constructor declaration with no access modifiers is **private**.

  (Enum constructors are always private to prevent other classes instantiating more enum constants.)