# access flag for default constructor in java

Tags: java, constructor, java-bytecode-asm

Could someone please tell which among
           `ACC_PUBLIC`, `ACC_PRIVATE`, `ACC_PROTECTED`
    is the access modifier for default constructor in java?

In some of the asm example I saw `ACC_PUBLIC` but I  could not find jvm specification related to this point.

Why there is not any need of package private access modifier?

Comment: A constructor might be any of the four. And package level access is also known as "default" level access.

Comment: I reformatted the question. Basically I meant default constructor

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13541386/default-access-modifier-for-a-java-constructor

Comment: @MrSimpleMind: that question asks for an explicit constructor, not a default constructor.

Comment: @nantitv: there is no package private access modifier bit, because the absence of all other bits implies package private access, much similar to the source code.

Comment: @Holger but it says an explicit constructor, even though the title says default. Did you read the entire thread... ;)

Comment: @MrSimpleMind: I’m not sure which question you are talking about now. The question you have linked is about *explicit* constructors, despite the misleading title. This question here is about *default* constructors, just as the title, the question and the accepted answer indicate. That’s why this is not a duplicate. One question is about explicit constructors, the other about the default constructor.

Comment: @Holger The linked question gives both answers, with Java Lang Spec references (JLS 8.8.9 and 6.6.1). So I find this as a duplicate . Seems that other agree this too...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The default constructor has the same accessibility as the class (see [JLS §8.8.9](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.9)).